# How to link two archive rules in servicenow?

Tags: servicenow, catalog

I am trying to archive catalog request record. Along with requests I need to archive request items(RITM) and tasks. I also need to archive catalog variables. For that I need to archive Options[ sc_item_option ] and Variable Ownership [ sc_item_option_mtom ] . I am trying to archive records which are older than 2.5 years. Number of requests are pretty huge. Each request have some variables. Archive Rules executes on batches like 1000 per run. If one request is archived then all the variables which are associated with this request also need to be archive. I tried to write independent archive rules for table but not able to achieve this. Do you guys have any idea regarding this problem?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please share what you have tried so far and where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: I have wrote independent archive rule for Request table and Variable ownership. I applied condition of creation date. But it is not satisfactory.